# Is there any harm in setting the AnalyticQueryCellMax to a high number?

Tags: performance, performancepoint

Is there any harm setting this to 10000000? Will it leave a large foot print on memory and therefore paralyze the servers (or farm)? (or the backend sqlserver) or anything that is involved processing this?

> Set-SPPerformancePointServiceApplication -identity "PerformancePoint Service Application" -AnalyticQueryCellMax 10000000